# Warning:cannot remove stale file <file name>: No such file or directory

Tags: swift, xcodebuild

When building our project (written in Swift building with Xcode 9 or AppCode) the first thing that appears in the build log is 1000s (1810) lines of...

> Warning:cannot remove stale file '[file name]': No such file or directory

The ONLY link I have found on the internet that includes this is the Apple swift-llbuild GitHub repository... https://github.com/apple/swift-llbuild/commit/9277b2ceb3ca76ea146baae09f16ba524cd820df

I'm currently trying to find why our project build times are slow and this is the next thing I've decided to investigate.

Any idea why this is happening? Like I said, it happens thousands of times each build (apart from the initial build after a clean).

All the files are in the DerivedData directory.

Most of them are source files but with `filename.o` instead of `.swift`. Some of them are `.plist` files some are storyboards or nibs.

I have removed the various build scripts we have one by one to see if any of them are causing this but nothing changed.